# Percent Width Adds to 100%, But Displayed On Two Lines

Tags: html, css

This appears on one line:

```
<label style="display:inline-block;width:30%">xxx</label>
<span style="display:inline-block;width:69%">hey</span>
```

This appears on 2:

```
<label style="display:inline-block;width:30%">xxx</label>
<span style="display:inline-block;width:70%">hey</span>
```

Why?

Comment: show us the rest of the code or a fiddle, could be many things

Comment: Its maybe because of padding or margin

Comment: Oh, they are inline blocks! There is a space between them.

Comment: Is this really all the CSS that gets applied to those elements?  Maybe some browser default styles that apply to them?  Because any margin, padding or border could make it them wider than 70%/30%.

Comment: Assign float:left to both elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `inline-block` elements are [white-space dependent](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), that `1%` is the white-space caused by this display value.

You can either manually remove the white-space between the `<label>` and the `<span>` or you can comment the white-space out by starting a comment at the end of one line and ending it on the next

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Would be better if you mentioned solutions though: Either put the elements on one line, or you could start a comment on the end of one line and end it on the next.

Comment: @biziclop That has nothing to do with this answer and is a horrible solution anyway.

Comment: @Adrift Links can die. You should always post code in the answer itself.